# How to use .create() function in sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've read the documentation of sails.js but still I have no idea where should I use and write `.create()`, `.find()` etc methods. I know how to define routes in routes.js and how to define controllers. I have created the database connection either.

I know how to use restful and shortcut routes to insert/fetch data from database. But I didn't find anything related to using `.create()` like methods. I found some but they were using Angular.js and Ajax. I didn't understand a thing at all.

Is there any good tutorial where I can learn using models and their methods(how, why and where to write them) without using Angular.js?

Answer (score 0):

In Sails.js,

Firstly we have to create api, So for example if we need method **create** for a user. Then we generate api **user** by typing this command in command prompt

```
sails generate api user
```

Then **User.js** file is generated in api/models folder and
**UserController.js** is generated in api/controllers folder.

Then we have add schema to User.js file

**In User.js**

```
module.exports = {
        attributes : {
                lastname : {
                        type : 'string'
                },
                firstname : {
                        type : 'string'
                }
        }
}
```

We have to write create, find, update and delete methods in UserController.js file. For now will add only create method.

**In UserController.js**

```
module.exports = {

      create: function(req, res, next, callback) {
        var params = req.body;

          //create a user
          User.create(params, function(err, createdData) {
              if(err){
                return res.badRequest({
                              error: err
                         });
               } else {
                 return res.json({
                            data : createdData
                 });
               }
          });
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This gave me a basic idea. Could you please tell where did you learn this?

Comment: And secondly, if I have to insert the data in a particular table, how would User.create() know which table to insert the data?

Comment: While learning any framework search for example or sample projects on github and refer the code.

Comment: What about 2nd comment?

Comment: User is the table here which has lastname and firstname as columns, you have use the create method to insert data. The create method can be accessed via route. So if the route for example is /user/create for create method. Then you can use postman (it is client to access your api) to insert data. The url will be http://localhost:3000/user/create and you can send json as request body that may look like this { "lastname": "Obama", "firstname" : "Barack"}. Then the data will be inserted in the database configured in SailsJs , in user table

Comment: So a different model for each table?

Comment: Yes, every table will have different columns so they have to be defined in models.

Comment: Ok. Now I'm using your code and inserting data in a table using default route `/user/create` and giving JSON data in postman. It works. However, same works with route `/user/` Why is that?

Comment: Because in config/blueprints.js file, rest  is true and shortcuts is true due to which you can access create using /user. To disable this behavior set rest to false and shortcuts to false in config/blueprints.js file.

Comment: Bro, the `User.create` you have defined is not working at all. The items are created but this thing is not utilized. You know why? Because res.json inside this method should show something like this: `{"data" : .......}` but it only shows the data without it's "data" title we have provided in res.json. What do you say?

Comment: You  may want to answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761335/why-res-json-not-working

Comment: You are using res.send({}) instead of res.json({}) right?

Comment: Both didn't make any difference.

Comment: Did you try to print the object that is {status: "success",data: createdData} before sending it via res.json or res.send ?

Comment: That problem is solved. Can you answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764940/how-to-get-data-from-other-table-using-a-column-data-from-a-different-table