# Why res.json() not working?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js

I'm new to **sails.js** and I'm trying to learn how to use models and controllers together. For that I have created the code given below. Now when I visit **....../corporate_info** I see all the required fields in JSON format in PostMan. But it doesn't seem to be 'coming from' the `res.json({})` I have defined in `corporate_info.find()` because the response doesn't have a property "data" in it. It should be actually {data : mydata} ?

**blueprints.js**

```
rest: false
```

Corporate_infoController

```
module.exports = {
    operations: function (req, res, next) {
        var params = req.body;
        Corporate_info.find(params, function (err, createdData) {
            if (err) {
                res.badRequest({
                    error: err
                });
            } else {
                return res.json({
                    status: "success",
                    data: createdData
                });
            }
        });
```

**Corporate_info.js** (model)

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'corporate_info',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      size: 11
    },
    fname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 100
    },
    lname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 100
    },
    country_code: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 45
    },
    mobile: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      size: 100
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 100
    },
    address: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 100
    },
    userid: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: false,
      size: 11
    },
    imei_number: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false
    },
    fullname: function(){
      return "Fullname: "+fname+" "+lname;
    }
  }
};
```

**Connections.js**

```
...
 mysqlAdapter: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
      password: '',
    database: 'rockcity_followme'
  }
...
```

**models.js**

```
...
connection: 'mysqlAdapter',
  migrate: 'safe'
...
```

Comment: where is res.json()

Comment: Edited the details, please check.

Comment: Try `console.log(createdData)`. then give me the response

Comment: Can you answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764940/how-to-get-data-from-other-table-using-a-column-data-from-a-different-table

Comment: I answer already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818088/why-doesnt-add-insert-value-in-the-column