# Why doesn't .add() insert value in the column?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, model-associations

I'm trying sails.js **association** using **one way reference** (according to **sails.js in action** book). Now, the value of owner is successfully inserted in **owner** column, but value in **cars** column is not inserted.

When I tried `console.log(foundDriver)` and `console.dir(foundDriver)`, it showed following things:

**{ id: 1, Name: 'asdf' }**

**{ cars: [Getter/Setter], id: 1, Name: 'asdf' }**

My tables (1: **driver**, 2: **car**):

[image]
[image]

CODE:

Car.js

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mysqlAdapter',
  tableName: 'car',
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      primaryKey: true
    },
    Name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    Brand: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    Model: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    owner: {
      model: 'driver'
    }
  }
};
```

Driver.js

```
 module.exports = {
 connection: 'mysqlAdapter',
 tableName: 'driver',
 attributes: {
   id: {
     type: 'integer',
     primaryKey: true
   },
   Name: {
     type: 'string'
   },
   cars: {
     collection: 'car'
   }
 }
};
```

CarController.js

```
    module.exports = {
    createCars: function (req, res) {
        Driver.findOne({
            id: 1
        }).exec(function (err, foundDriver) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Err1" + foundDriver);
            }
            if (!foundDriver) {
                console.log("Err2");
            }
            Car.create({
                Name: "car1",
                Brand: "brnd",
                Model: "mdl",
                owner: foundDriver.id
            }).exec(function (err, createdCar) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Err3");
                }
                foundDriver.cars.add(createdCar.id);
                    foundDriver.save(function (err) {
                     if (err) {
                         console.log(foundDriver);

                      }
                          return res.json({id: 100});
                    });
            });
        });
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be inserted because its 'virtual' data. When you want to get those data you need to join those 2 tables.

```
Driver.find({

}).populate('cars').exec(function(error, drivers){

});
```

Query sent to database will look more like this

```
select * from driver inner join car where driver.id = car.owner
```

Comment: Then what is the purpose of .add() and .save() functions? They aren't mean to insert data actually? But store virtually? Did I get it right?

Comment: This is how association works. You do not same data in many places.

Comment: They do not * same data?

Comment: Do not store. Sorry.