# How to get data from other table using a column data from a different table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

I have two tables:

table1

```
id | email
1 | email1
2 | email2
```

table2

```
userid | username
2      | user1
3      | user2
```

Now, using sails.js associations, I want to do this:

I have a username = **user1**. Using this, first I need the **userid** of this user1, then using this userid, I want to access the **email** from **table1**.

I want to do this using models, controllers and associations only. Is it possible?

EDIT:

The tables I have provided above are sample tables for my original tables. Here I'm posting my actual models for actual tables:

**Corporate_info.js** (For table1. Actual table name: corporate_info)

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'corporate_info',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  connection: 'mysqlAdapter',
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      size: 11
    },
    fname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 100
    },
    lname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 100
    },
    country_code: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 45
    },
    mobile: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      size: 100
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 100
    },
    address: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 100
    },
    userid: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: false,
      size: 11
    },
    imei_number: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false
    },
    owner: {
      model: 'Rc_users',
      unique: true
    }

  }
};
```

**Rc_users.js** (for table2. Actual table name: rc_users)

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'rc_users',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  connection: 'mysqlAdapter',
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      size: 11
    },
    country_code: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 45
    },
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
      size: 255
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 40
    },
    code: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      index: true,
      size: 40
    },
    active: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 3
    },
    last_login: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      index: true,
      size: 11
    },
    last_session: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      index: true,
      size: 40
    },
    blocked: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 3
    },
    tries: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    last_try: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      index: true,
      size: 11
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 255
    },
    mask_id: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 6
    },
    group_id: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 6
    },
    activation_time: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      index: true,
      size: 11
    },
    last_action: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      index: true,
      size: 11
    },
    firstname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      size: 40
    },
    lastname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      size: 40
    },
    companyname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      size: 100
    },
    reg_type: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 11
    },
    rc_web_userid: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      size: 100
    },
    admin_id: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: false,
      size: 11
    },
    device_token: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      size: 500
    },
    device_type: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      size: 45
    },
    userMobile: {
      collection: 'corporate_info',
      via: 'owner'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Simple join: `SELECT t.id,t.email,s.username FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON(id = userid)`

Comment: I don't want to use queries.

Comment: I want to use this type of code: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/associations/one-to-one.md Isn't it possible using it?

Comment: I don't know this type of programming , that's the MySQL query to generate your desired results.

Comment: It is possible without using queries, I'm sure.

Comment: I am too, every thing is possible through a variety of options .

Answer (score 0):

You should create model like this

> I assumed that you want to do one-by-one association. So this is it.

api/models/Email.js

```
attributes: {
    email : {
        type: 'email',
        unique: true
    },
    owner : {
        model:'user',  //here put your model name 
        unique: true   //put unique here because it's one by one association
   }
}
```

api/models/User.js

```
attributes: {
   username : {
     type: 'string',
     unique: true
   },
   userEmail : {
      collection:'email', //here is also model name
      via: 'owner'
   }
}
```

Then

Get user from email

```
Email.find().populate('owner')
```

Get email from user

```
User.find().populate('userEmail')
```

Now you can access to your data both from your two model.

Try to print two command above you will see that your data contain the data from related table.

```
Email.find().populate('owner').exec(function(err, records) {
    res.json(records)
});
```

This is my response.

```
[
    {
        "owner": {
            "username": "test",
            "id": 1,
            "createdAt": "2016-11-23T13:45:06.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2016-11-23T13:45:06.000Z"
        },
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "id": 1,
        "createdAt": "2016-11-23T13:45:06.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-11-23T13:45:06.000Z"
    }
]
```

More information : http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-one

Comment: Do I need to define any foreign/primary key in the table along with this?

Comment: Sails model create primary key by default. You can see that in database. I don't have much experience in Sails with mysql but it shoud be the same with my mongoDB.

Also for the foreign key, we don't really need it. Waterline CRM will automatic do that for you. Only two things we need to do is just told them which is this one belong to. That's `model:'user'` I put in Email model. And set the owner for its in User model via `collection:'email'`. But If you really need `ID` for something else just add it.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. It says: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'table1.owner' in 'field list'

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your model please.

Comment: Please check the detail.

Comment: Try using model name instead of table name.

Comment: Wait, I'm getting all details from Rc_users table along with userMobile: [ ]. Why is it blank for all results?

Comment: Did you add the data ?

Comment: First, can you please tell where should I read about this? Actually I don't understand what you did. Where can I learn this and implement it accordingly?

Comment: Did you do migration yet after you change model structure ? this is work for me.

Comment: I already put the link in my answer since i edit it first time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818088/why-doesnt-add-insert-value-in-the-column Can you answer this?